# CSS3: Grow div from left to right while preserving original position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to create a calendar using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  This calendar is meant to display upcoming/past events, and I'm struggling to get my event blocks to fill the rest of the calendar days from left to right.  You can see an example of the current calendar below.

[image]

Here's an example of how my table cells are structured within my project:

```css
.cell-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.date-label{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-cell{
  display: flex;
}

.inner-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.event{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-cell">
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">23</label>
      <div class="event">Event @4:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">24</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">25</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the snippet, my event continues to expand both left and right, instead of expanding explicitly to the right.  I've tried using `position: sticky` and `position: absolute` but both end in the same result.

Is there any way that I can restrict the direction that the div expands? or is this not a possibility?  Any and all feedback would be appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `justify-content` to `flex-start`
and removing `align-items: center` in the `inner-container` class.
Add `align-self: center;` to the `date-label` class to keep it centered :

```css
.cell-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.date-label{
  font-weight: bold;
  align-self: center;
}

.table-cell{
  display: flex;
}

.inner-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.event{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-cell">
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">23</label>
      <div class="event">Event @4:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">24</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">25</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the the `align-items` property in the inner container to expand from the left. (You could also set it to `start` or `normal`). If you want the date number to remain centered, you have to set the `align-self` property to center. See below.

```css
.cell-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.date-label{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-cell{
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.inner-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.event{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-cell">
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">23</label>
      <div class="event">Event @4:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">24</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <label class="date-label">25</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `left` is not an allowed value for `align-items` property

Comment: I think you meant to say ```flex-start```

Comment: @Joulss and michael: you are, of course, correct.